# How to use Rolle's Theorem to prove the following?:

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

> For each $\lambda$, the function $f(x)=x^3-\frac 32x^2+\lambda$ does
>   not have two distinct zeros in $[0,1]$.

Comment: Can the derivative be $0$ anywhere on $(0,1)$?

Comment: What does Rolle’s theorem require between any two zeroes?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thanks, both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$f'(x)=3x^2-3x=3x(x-1)$. If $f$ has two distinct zeros in $[0,1]$, then by Rolle's theorem there would be $z\in (0,1)$ with $f'(z)=0$, a contradiction.